# Is it plausible to index a field that is constantly changing, or will the constant writing diminish performance?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, filesort

I'm currently indexing one of my MySQL tables and have come to a point where I need advice from an expert on how to proceed.

The table is structured similar to the following:

```
ProductID - INT - UNSIGNED - NOT NULL - AUTO INCREMENT - PRIMARY KEY
ProductName - VARCHAR(64) - NOT NULL
ProductViews - INT - UNSIGNED - NOT NULL
```

The only fields that is used in WHERE clauses is ProductID.
The only field that is used in ORDER BY is ProductViews.

The table is fairly large so a typical query (when joined to another table) can take some time.
Running an EXPLAIN on a typical query shows that due to the ProductViews field, MySQL is displaying "Extra: Using where; Using filesort"

I would like to index ProductViews to get rid of the filesort, however the value in the field gets incremented by 1 on every visit to the page.

Is it plausible to index a field that is constantly changing, or will the constant writing diminish performance? Is this is a situation where I can't really do much and have to live with the filesort problem?

Answer (score 2):

You're asking if the benefit of the index outweighs the cost.  I'd say a filesort is so expensive it's worth using an index here.

But the only real answer can be found by measuring.  Set up criteria (like web page loading speed) and measure it with and without the index.

Comment: As you say, it's difficult to come up with a definitive answer.

In this case, I've found that adding the index results in a change, but not significant. I've not yet decided how to proceed, but I feel that I shouldn't index that field since the resultset is likely to be cached anyway (using memcache).